# How to avoid server (using python websockets) from getting hanged up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, websocket, supervisord

I have written a server which sends data using python's websockets. This script is run on Supervisord and it was working just fine. All of a sudden, the client is unable to get anything from the server. I stopped the supervisor and tried to run the script manually and it works just fine. I am not sure as to what I am doing wrong.

Server Script:

```
from __future__ import print_function
#!/usr/bin/env python
import asyncio
import datetime
import random
import websockets


import ast
from collections import defaultdict
import csv
import datetime
from itertools import chain
import json
import os
import operator
import sys
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

try:
    client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    db = client["Bubble"]
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

start_match = datetime.datetime.strptime(
    "2018-07-01 18:00:00", '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

collection = "CRODEN_R16"

async def hello(websocket, path):
    entity_name = await websocket.recv()
    print(entity_name)
    file = open("set_start_match.txt", "r")
    for line in file:
        start_today = datetime.datetime.strptime(
            line.split('.')[0], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    print(start_today)

    while True:
        now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        diff = now - start_today
        request_match = start_match + diff
        print(diff)
        count = 0
        for post in db[collection].find():
            print(count)
            if "emotion" not in post.keys():
                print("Ignored")
                continue
            if post["timeStamp"] > request_match:
                if post["entity_name"] == entity_name:
                    print("Satisfied")
                    currDict = {}
                    currDict["entity"] = post["entity_name"]
                    currDict["emotion"] = max(
                        post["emotion"].items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))[0]
                    currDict["profile_image"] = post["userProfile"]
                    currDict["tweet"] = post["tweet"].encode('utf-8')
                    currDict_json = json.dumps(currDict, default=str)
                    print(currDict["tweet"])
                    await websocket.send(currDict_json)
                    del currDict
                else:
                    print("Ignored")
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)


try:
    start_server = websockets.serve(hello, '0.0.0.0', 8765)
    print("Start entity server")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Client Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# WS client example

import asyncio
import websockets

async def hello():
    async with websockets.connect(
            'ws://A.B.C.D:8765') as websocket:
        name = input("What's your name? ")

        await websocket.send(name)
        while True:
            greeting = await websocket.recv()
            print(greeting)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: there's a lot of code here. what have you done to debug already? Also can you provide any logs you might have?

Comment: @MatthewStory I could not know the reason why it stopped and hence no debugging in the code. I think I need to close the sockets. Can you tell me how? And no, no logs are generated.